# WSO2 Samples failing

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working on setting up and understaind WSO2 ESB and i was going through the samples and set up. 
I was looking at this sample, but well, any i tried from the first four failed:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Sample+3%3A+Local+Registry+Entry+Definitions%2C+Reusable+Endpoints+and+Sequences

So, i start the ESB (Management Console is running fine), that works fine. I can build the SimpleStockQuoteService and i can start the sample AXIS2 server. I can open the wsdl from the browser, so that piece looks fine.
When i run the client code from command line

```
ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService -Dtrpurl=http://localhost:8280/
```

It gets to the axis2 server (i can see it in the logs: "Mon Mar 11 16:53:37 CET 2013 samples.services.SimpleStockQuoteService :: Generating quote for : IBM")), it gets to the ESB (i can see it in the log, too), but suddenly, when it is trying to forward (?) or pass (?) the message, the connection is suddenly dropped. This is what i see in the log:

```
[2013-03-11 16:53:37,701]  INFO - LogMediator Text = Sending quote request, version = 0.1, direction = incoming
[2013-03-11 16:53:37,830] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: A l├®tezo kapcsolatot a t├ívoli ├íllom├ís k├®nyszer├¡tetten bez├írta
java.io.IOException: A l├®tezo kapcsolatot a t├ívoli ├íllom├ís k├®nyszer├¡tetten bez├írta
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:25)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:233)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:206)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.fill(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:93)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.fillBuffer(AbstractMessageParser.java:113)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:150)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultServerIOEventDispatch.inputReady(DefaultServerIOEventDispatch.java:154)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:340)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:318)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

"A l├®tezo kapcsolatot a t├ívoli ├íllom├ís k├®nyszer├¡tetten bez├írta
java.io.IOException: A l├®tezo kapcsolatot a t├ívoli ├íllom├ís k├®nyszer├¡tetten bez├írta" This piece is having bad encoding and is in hungarian, it means something like :"Connection was closed forcefully by remote host"

I don't really know what is going wrong... Any ideas?

I'm on Windows 7. I've downloaded the latest WSO2 ESB (wso2esb-4.6.0.zip)

Comment: Not sure whay are you gettting hungarian caharcters in the middle. Can you set an system environment[1] property and restart the server and check? JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: I was thinking maybe the OS is blocking something (Win7). I'll try your advice, thanks in advance!